# create an interface to edit PHP variables

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

i use PHP variables in one of my projects and i have a file named variables.php which stores all the variables value.

```
<?php
$txt="Hello World!";
$x=16;
?>
```

I want to create an interface to edit that file's variables instead of directly editing it in a text editor
By interface, i mean simple text and logical fields....a form. I searched for it but i have no clue from where to start
Can someone give me a clue of what i should be doing to create the mentioned thing.

*note: i don't want to use a database*

Comment: What specifically stops you from doing what you want to do?

Comment: [Why don't you want to use a database?](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Comment: Not constructive? Really? I'm voting for reopening =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it's easier to use array variables for this purpose and use `var_export` to store its value inside another .php file.

```
$a = array('var' => 'test', 'nr' => 4);

file_put_contents('myvars.php', '<?php return ' . var_export($a, true) . '; ?>', LOCK_EX);
```

Then to fetch the array again:

```
$a = include('myvars.php');
```

Saving into a .php file has the benefit of speed.

Answer (score 1):

How about making a simple form, and when you process it, write the data to the variables.php file using http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

note that you need to provide writing permissions to this php file, which makes it a risk. there are different ways to make it secure. make sure the permissions are not global. make sure you use a password. and another solution is to write the variables not directly to a php file but to a text file, and make the php file take the variables from there...

tell me if you further assistance...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a XML file that defines the variables that should be able to edit and of which type they are and their value:

```
<xml>
    <var name="txt" type="title" php="string">Hello World!</var>
    <var name="16" type="integer" php="int">16</var>
</xml>
```

You can then create a [XML transformation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) that turns that XML into a HTML form.

You can then create a XML processing that parses the form submission and stores the new values into the XML file.

You can then create a second XML transformation that is able to store that information as PHP code with the variable notation.

Your main code can then include that file.

Comment: That's kind of overkill, isn't it? And escaping values to be valid PHP code via XSLT? Ugh..

Comment: Complicated, okay, could be, however, this is using standardized components, so not complicated as resources exist. Additionally, this is very safe to maintain over time. Maybe that's already the overhead, so if you don't need maintenance, shitbake something that does regex search and replace and just don't care. @ThiefMaster: http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php